# Workaround for a bad neutral cable

Tags: wiring, neutral

Question: A 3-wire socket (hot, neutral, ground) in my bathroom has stopped working due to a bad neutral wire.  Can I safely disconnect the bad neutral wire completely, and move the ground wire to the neutral connector to get the socket working again?   I have verified that there are 0.0 volts between ground and a nearby (working) neutral wire.

Background:  I believe this failure can be traced to the installation of a new deck in the back of the house a couple of years ago, when the workers broke several cables between floors when they were pulling out beams from the old deck.  The contractor brought in an electrician to fix the obvious failures, but I didn't notice that this bathroom socket (which is the last of a daisy chain of outlets) apparently ended up with a loose or broken neutral wire which causes intermittent failure, especially during prolonged rain spells.  I'm speculating that the break is about 30 feet away from the socket, buried somewhere in the space between the floors and virtually inaccessible.  I have considered installing a connecting wire from a nearby good neutral wire from the bathroom lights, but there is no easy way to do this without removing wall paper, sheet rock, etc.   The first socket in this particular daisy chain is in another bathroom, and is a GFCI socket.  Second question:  Would the ground to neutral connection I am proposing trip the GFCI?

The intermittent failures (which can last for hours or days) are driving me nuts.  Any other suggestions for how to fix this without breaking into the sheet rock would be welcome.

Comment: **Heck no.  Neutral is not ground.** Abusing the ground as a neutral is dangerous for several reasons, one is that any fault in the grounding system will electrify everything that's supposed to be grounded, and you could get killed touching a light switch cover screw.   You can retrofit grounds, but never neutrals; you must run hot+neutral together in the same cable or conduit.  I'm not writing an answer as I expect this will end up duplicating another question.  It's asked a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Don't walk, but RUN to your closest licensed electrician to fix this problem.

There is no workaround.

It simply needs to be fixed correctly.

This is a life-threatening situation.  Until you get a contractor out to look at it, avoid all contact with that outlet.

Comment: Hi SDsolar,  could I get you to elaborate on the reason for the danger, assuming that the only problem is a broken neutral, and that I do not do what I proposed?  As I mentioned, the circuit is GFCI protected, and of course the circuit breaker is also working properly.  Just curious as to what scenario you are envisioning.   Many thanks!

Comment: @clivedaw - If you continue to use the intermittent outlet there will be current flow through a connection that is only sometimes closed. Problem is that the intermittent closed connection is not a good solid join of the wires. Such connection will be higher than normal resistance and when current flows through it heat will build up to the point of causing the wire insulation and surrounding materials to catch fire. This is not something you want to happen so thus the urgent need to get it fixed. (Review the history - a good number of fires are due to electrical problems).

Comment: To expand on Michael's correct comment, you say the breaker is working, but that is a non-issue. The high resistance connection can flow current well below the breaker's rating and still cause a VERY hot connection. It's all about Ohm's Law.

Comment: @clivedaw **Just no**.  I'm skeptical of "why not" questions because usually the goal is to rationalize/justify doing the bad thing anyway. Not gonna happen. If there was a way, we'd give it, but there just isn't.  **Curious?** OK, the craft is certainly learnable, but *learn the craft, not random bits*.  It's deep enough you can't do it as a drive-by. There's a lot of "because code says so" until you get deep enough into it that the puzzle pieces come together. They will, trust me.  At that point, the folly of the above will be *obvious*.

Comment: Hello @clivedaw, the danger is that a discharge of electricity could go through your body (which includes your heart) and the GFCI might not be able to sense it.  Just think of how many devices only have two-prong plugs - they generally use the neutral as a case ground.  But with no neutral, it is entirely possible that the path of least resistance will be out through someone touching the enclosure of the item or an exposed wire.  GFCI only works for 3-prong devices, remember, and only works if there is an electricity path going out through the ground prong.

Comment: Even more, misusing the safety grounding system as a current return **defeats its entire purpose**.  Making a point to tie metal things to safety ground completely backfires when they become "hot" because of a subsequent problem with neutral or ground.  Also it's madness to think the two surviving conductors in the damaged cable are intact. They could well be nicked or on the verge of shorting, make excessive heat and start a fire.  And GFCI's don't detect shorts. Not that one would even work in this configuration.

Comment: @Harper makes a very valid point.  Upvote.  There is indeed no reason to expect that a problem like this that suddenly appears is limited to just one of the wires.  Circuit breakers can allow a lot of power through before tripping, which definitely gives ample opportunity for a hot spot to become "too" hot and melt something or create an ignition source.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, everybody.  Based on this info, especially the potential for fire even if the breaker doesn't trip, I will go to the next-to-last outlet on the daisy chain and completely disconnect the final leg of the circuit.  Then I will consult with an electrician on the best way to bring an alternate circuit to power that outlet.

Comment: @SDsolar gfci's work on 2 conductors. They use a little inductive coil around each conductor to detect a current imbalance between them. In a functioning circuit, there should be precisely the same current flowing on the hot and grounded (neutral) conductors. Any difference and the gfci should trip.